# Controlling power bank via USB

Tags: usb, powerbanks

I've got only a basing electronic background and I'm more experienced in programming :)

I'm going to use some power bank (PB) device with USB connectors to provide power to my embedded system. I planned to let this device working independently (mostly without personal control of it) and just get the SoC or SoP (state of charge/power) from this power bank. In case of low power of PB I wanted to just notify me via i.e. SMS and then shut down my embedded system.

The question is: do the power banks provide end user with such a communication protocol for gathering SoC/SoP from this power bank?

I know there is something like Power Delivery in USB and I was looking in Linux kernel sources for support for such a feature but found only:

https://docs.kernel.org/power/charger-manager.html

and not sure this is the right pointer I should read to start with controlling power bank?

It might look like there is some generic way for controlling power banks (as the charger manager exists in Linux) but I'm not sure if I'm not going wrong way.

Any other pointers how could I start this project?

Comment: While it's certainly possible to design a power bank which is able to notify connected devices of its state-of-charge (and/or any other parameters) as if it were a UPS, I've never met or heard of one which does so.

Comment: This isn't really the target application for power banks, so there's no real incentive to add these features.

Comment: Make one! Add a USB hub to it and hook into that one with a USB client capable MCU and you’ll have all the options from there. You can make it appear as a serial port which spits out SoC.

Comment: @winny: Hm... I'm not sure if writing my own BMS would be an easy task... I assume that this is what you suggested me :)

Comment: No need, you can either read SOC from the BMS or just measure the voltage.

Comment: @winny: Ooops, you are right - I need to only read the status and don't write the fully functional BMS :) But... from the other side I'd need some knowledge how to read the current SoC from available on the market and ready to use solutions... 
I was also thinking about measuring the voltage but if I'm not wrong there is not simple conversion like "voltage -> SoC". Am i right? AFAIR this is the role of BMS to keep tracking amount of electric charge in battery measuring the current in time... Or maybe I'm wrong again? :)

Comment: Yes, a voltage -> SoC look up table is how I would do it unless it’s readily available from the BMS via SPI or I2C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, USB power banks generally don't provide state of charge info over USB.

They might also not even know or care about their own state of charge in any way, as they might just shut down when battery voltage is low enough to be considered empty.

Having a USB powerbank monitor it's own battery like a laptop would mean there must be added electronics for battery monitoring and some interface to extract that information, standard or vendor specific. A laptop does this in a vendor specific way but the information is exposed via an API which the OS/drivers/programs can utilize. And sure, UPSes with USB connection allows a desktop PC OS to know the battery status, but the PC is the USB host and UPS is the USB device.